# rename files with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying this script to rename a series of files with unwanted characters:

```
$stdout.sync
print "Enter the file search query: "; search  = gets.chomp
print "Enter the target to replace: "; target  = gets.chomp
print "  Enter the new target name: "; replace = gets.chomp
Dir['*'].each do |file|
  # Skip directories
  next unless File.file?(file)
  old_name = File.basename(file,'.*')
  if old_name.include?(search)
    # Are you sure you want gsub here, and not sub?
    # Don't use `old_name` here, it doesn't have the extension
    new_name = File.basename(file).gsub(target,replace)
    File.rename( file, new_path )
    puts "Renamed #{file} to #{new_name}" if $DEBUG
  end
end
```

I would like to be able to pass as a prompt argument the path of the directory that contains the files to be renamed, and then I modified the script as follows:

```
$stdout.sync
path = ARGV[0]
print "Enter the file search query: "; search  = gets.chomp
print "Enter the target to replace: "; target  = gets.chomp
print "  Enter the new target name: "; replace = gets.chomp
Dir[path].each do |file|
  # Skip directories
  next unless File.file?(file)
  old_name = File.basename(file,'.*')
  if old_name.include?(search)
    # Are you sure you want gsub here, and not sub?
    # Don't use `old_name` here, it doesn't have the extension
    new_name = File.basename(file).gsub(target,replace)
    File.rename( file, new_path )
    puts "Renamed #{file} to #{new_name}" if $DEBUG
  end
end
```

get this error message:

renamefiles.rb:3:in `gets': Is a directory @ io_fillbuf - fd:7

why?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Are you sure that this code produces that error, on your machine? However, there also seems to be some confusion about whether `path` or `search` are being used as the search parameter....

Comment: @Dennis : Looks like you have messed up your `$stdin` somehow. How did you invoke the program?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an argument such that ARGV is populated the ruby interpreter will assume you mean `Kernel#gets` which expects a filename.

You should be able to fix this by using `STDIN.gets` so you would have

```
print "Enter the file search query: "; search  = STDIN.gets.chomp
print "Enter the target to replace: "; target  = STDIN.gets.chomp
print "  Enter the new target name: "; replace = STDIN.gets.chomp
```

Comment: I solved with:
print "Enter the directory path:"; path = gets.chomp

Answer (score 0):

I have refined the code so that the file extension is not changed, and the directories are also renamed.
I have two problems left to solve:

-the passage of the path from argv (the path is not correctly recognized)
-I would like to recursively rename, even files in directories

```
path = ARGV[0]
print "Enter the file search query: "; search  = gets.chomp
print "Enter the target to replace: "; target  = gets.chomp
print "  Enter the new target name: "; replace = gets.chomp
Dir::chdir('/Users/dennis/Documents/test/daRinominare')
Dir['*'].each do |file|
  #puts file
  if Dir.exist?(file)
    directoryList = file
    old_name = File.basename(file)
    new_name = old_name.gsub(target,replace)
    File.rename( file, new_name)
  end

  next unless File.file?(file)
  old_name = File.basename(file,'.*')
  extension = File.extname(file)
  if old_name.include?(search)
    new_name = old_name.gsub(target,replace) + extension
    File.rename( file, new_name)
    puts "Renamed #{file} to #{new_name}" if $DEBUG
  end
end
```

Comment: So, is this a new question @Denis?  The first question related to why you got the error `gets is a directory @ io_fillbuf` which was to do with the difference between Kernel.gets (which will read files from the arguments passed) and IO.gets (which you can call from STDIN to get user input)

Comment: The script only renames files: now I would like it to rename directories as well

Answer (score 0):

[`Kernel.gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) reads from [`ARGF`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/ARGF.html), which acts as an aggregate IO to read from the files named in `ARGV`, unless `ARGV` is empty in which case `ARGF` reads from `$stdin`.  `ARGF.gets` will generate errors like `EISDIR` and `ENOENT` if `ARGV` has entries which are paths to directories or paths that don't exist.

If you want to read user input, use `$stdin.gets`

(The difference between `$stdin` and `STDIN`: The constant `STDIN` is the process standard input stream, and is the initial value of the variable `$stdin` which can be reassigned to change the source used by library methods; see [globals](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/globals_rdoc.html).  I use `$stdin` unless I need to change `$stdin` and also use `STDIN` for another purpose.)